# Using SQL, have components of a product appear horizontally beside product

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to have all components that are part of a product appear on the same row as each other

I have two tables

**PRODUCT**

```
ID  PRODUCTNUMBER   DESCRIPTION                                 TYPE        STATUS  KIT
1 (PK)  121         1 Apples and 1 Oranges                      FRUIT PACK  YES     Y
2       122         2 Brocolli & 2 Carrots                      VEG PACK    NO      Y
3       123         3 Strawberries and 3 Blueberries and 1 Pear FRUIT PACK  YES     Y
4       124         2 Plums and 1 Pears                         FRUIT PACK  YES     Y
5       125         4 Grapes and 2 Cabbage                      COMBO PACK  YES     Y
6       126         Apple                                       FRUIT       YES     N
7       127         Orange                                      FRUIT       YES     N
8       128         Pear                                        FRUIT       YES     N
9       129         Onion                                       VEG         NO      N
10      130         Blueberry                                   FRUIT       YES     N
11      131         Strawberry                                  FRUIT       YES     N
12      132         Plum                                        FRUIT       YES     N
```

**PRODUCTCOMPONENT**

```
PRODUCT QTY
5   55
6   45
7   21
8   12
9   0
10  20
11  25
12  50
```

My SQL query should return:

```
SKU Description                 COMPONENT1  QTY1    COMPONENT2  QTY2    COMPONENT3  QTY3
121 1 Apples and 1 Oranges              Apple       55  Orange      45      
123 3 Strawberries and 3 Blueberries and 1 Pear Strawberries    25  Blueberry   20  Pear        12
124 2 Plums and 1 Pears             Plum        50  Pear        12
```

I tried:

```
SELECT 
    PRODUCT.CODE, PRODUCT.DESCRIPTION,
    PRODUCTCOMPONENT.PRODUCT, PRODUCTCOMPONENT.QTY
FROM
    PRODUCT 
INNER JOIN 
    PRODUCTCOMPONENT ON PRODUCTCOMPONENT.PRODUCT = PRODUCT.ID 
WHERE 
    PRODUCT.STATUS = YES
    AND PRODUCT.KIT = Y;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Apologies, after I Posted the format went bad

Comment: I need a little more information to make recommendations. How firm is the "in SQL" requirement? Is this information going to be pulled into some other application (such as Excel or a reporting tool?)

Comment: So I am going to export to CSV. A WMS will take that file and import it.

Comment: Okay, thank you. The next question is: what's the maximum number of components that can be in a kit?

Comment: I'll explain in my answer why you need to know that up-front.

Comment: 5 components max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is from memory, but I've verified the syntax with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5c20c9/2).

You are right that you need to start with `PRODUCT` and `PRODUCTCOMPONENT`. And the code you posted will give you the data you want -- but it won't have the answers in columns, just in rows.

So what you have is what I call a "rotation problem". You want to "swing" the data over 90 degrees (so to speak), and have multiple columns where you had multiple rows.

There is no automatic, built-in way to do this.  But there are indirect ways.

What you're going to have to do is left-outer-join `PRODUCTCOMPONENT` to `PRODUCT` once for every set of columns you want to display component information.

If you have 2 columns, you'd need to do it twice. Since your max is 5, you'll need to do it 5 times.

This is why I asked how many components you could have per item. If you had an indefinite number, you'd be out of luck, because there just isn't a simple way to
automatically extend columns out to the right for as many sets of rows you happen to have. You have to do a new left join clause for every additional possible component!

Here's an example of the 2-column case, which should show you how to do the 5-column case:

```
    -- In order to join to just the records from Row 1, we need to number them! 
    -- We'll do that in a CTE (Common Table Expression).
    ; 
    WITH Components as (
      -- I don't know all the columns in PRODUCTCOMPONENT, but you presumably have a
      -- parent and child ID. Substitute the true names of the columns for the 
      -- column names I'm using
      SELECT ParentId
           , ChildId
           , Product -- I am assuming this is the product name
           , Qty
           -- The following line will assign a line number to each component within
           -- a product. If there's a particular order you want the columns to appear in,
           -- change the "Order by" part of the ROW_NUMBER() OVER expression.
           , RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By ParentId  Order By ChildId)
      FROM   ProductComponent 
    )
    SELECT   Product.PRODUCTNUMBER as Code
           , Product.DESCRIPTION
           , Component1.Product as Component1
           , Component1.Qty as Qty1
           , Component2.Product as Component2
           , Component2.Qty as Qty2
    FROM     Product
         -- Note that since some products will have more components than others,
         -- you need to left-join to the Components CTE to make sure that rows are
         -- still returned even when they only have nulls.
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Components as Component1
           ON  Product.ID = Component1.ParentID
           AND Component1.RowNumber = 1
         -- The second clause of the JOIN means that you'll only get rows back
         -- from the CTE if the RowNumber assigned in the CTE is (in this case) 2.
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Components as Component2
           ON  Product.ID = Component2.ParentID
           AND Component2.RowNumber = 2
    WHERE   Product.STATUS = 'YES'
        AND Product.KIT = 'Y';
```

Comment: Thanks Ann for the super descriptive answer, really appreciate the time you took out of your day to do this.  It worked like a charm